# Javascript: How to redirect to another page after click play.png?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, redirect

I just bought movie script and I want to tweak something but I don't know how to do that. So, I hope you can help me.

With this code, when somebody clicks "play.png", the trailer will be played. However, I want to redirect to another page when they click play.png. How to do that ?

This is html:

```
                    <div id="trailer-mask" data-bind="click: showTrailer" data-src="{{ $title->trailer }}">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="{{ $title->background }}">
                        <div class="center"><img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('assets/images/play.png') }}"> </div>
                    </div>
```

This is javascript:

```
showTrailer: function() {
    var e = s("#trailer-mask");
    "default" == vars.trailersPlayer ? e.html('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="' + e.data("src") + '?autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0" wmode="opaque" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe></div>') : (-1 != e.data("src").indexOf("youtube") ? videojs("trailer", {
        techOrder: ["youtube"]
    }).src(e.data("src")).play() : videojs("trailer", {
        techOrder: ["html5", "flash"]
    }).src(e.data("src")).play(), e.css("display", "none"), s("#trailer").css("display", "block"), s("#social").css("top", 0).css("left", 0), s("#lists").css("top", 0).css("right", 0), videojs("trailer").on("userinactive", function() {
        s("#social").css("display", "none"), s("#lists").css("display", "none")
    }), videojs("trailer").on("useractive", function() {
        s("#social").css("display", "block"), s("#lists").css("display", "block")
    }))
},
```

With above code, if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$(".img-responsive").click(function(){
   window.location.href = "http://your-website.com";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fire a redirect when clicking that image (which has a class called `.img-responsive`):

```
$(".img-responsive").click(function(){
   window.location = "http://www.go-to-link.com";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Javascript Way:**

```
location.href="http://www.domain.com/";
```

Open in new Tab:

```
window.location("http://www.domain.com/");
```

**The jQuery Way:**

```
$(location).attr('href','http://www.domain.com/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your js function:

```
showTrailer: function() {
    window.location.href = "http://yourDESIREDurl.com";
},
```

if you have a dynamically generated div then in jQuery you can use event delegation this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.img-responsive', function(){
    window.location.href = "http://yourDESIREDurl.com";
});
```